# Find the number of nonnegative integer solutions of $(x_1+1)(x_2+1)(x_3+1)(x_4+1) = (9-x_1)(5-x_2)(3-x_3)(2-x_4)$.

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I understand the Stars and Bars (balls in bins) method that is commonly used to tackle questions like "Find the number of nonnegative integer solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3 +x_4= n$." and various extensions of this problem, but I am curious if this can be applied for questions like:

$$(x_1+1)(x_2+1)(x_3+1)(x_4+1) = (9-x_1)(5-x_2)(3-x_3)(2-x_4).$$

where all factors on the right hand side are nonnegative integers. The solution to this question is $6$, where $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ is either $(4,1,1,1)$, $(3,2,2,0)$, $(1,3,1,1)$, $(7,1,1,0)$, $(5,2,0,1)$, or $(4,3,1,0)$. How can I approach this question combinatorically? Can this similar approach be extended for $n$ variables? Thank you!

Comment: To start off, what is the possible range of $x_4$?

Comment: Also, what makes you think the problem has anything to do with stars-and-bars or balls-in-bins?

Comment: $x_4$ can be $0$ or $1$. All factors on the right hand side should be nonnegative numbers. I will edit my question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: It's going to be a case analysis -- there's no avoiding it. Just try to develop the tree of choices to minimize the number of branches.

Comment: @quasi Stars and bars is usually used for questions that ask for the number of nonnegative integer solutions to questions like $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = m$ or $x_1x_2x_3...x_n = m$. I thought it was the natural approach to this question.

Comment: Maybe it is, but I don't see it. You don't have a constant $m$. Also, the product version requires knowledge of prime factors to tie in with stars-and-bars.

Comment: I would characterize the strategy to be used as "organized search", or "intelligent case analysis", but no magic bullet. Of course, maybe there is a magic bullet that I just don't see (and if so, I hope it's not aimed at me).

Comment: As you progress, inequalities are key. For example, at least one factor must be greater than or equal to its complement on the other side. Similarly for less than or equal to. Parity might also yield some reductions at some point in the analysis -- maybe, maybe not.

Comment: Since $0\leq x_2\leq 4$ and $0\leq x_2\leq 2$ and $0\leq x_4\leq 1$ there are $(5)(3)(2)=30$ potential values for $(x_2,x_3,x_4).$ Each of them yields a linear equation in $x_1,$ which may or may not have a non-negative integer solution  for $x_1.$

Comment: I understand this is problem of contest math. If  $x_1>x_2>・・・$, 
 the equation $\leq 270$, but this is useless. $x_1=2,x_1=6,x_2=4$ are impossible since LHD is not multiple of 7, RHD is not multiple of 7 and 5 on each cases. Since this problem has 30 potential values by previous comment, you only investigate all case.